# "kill -9 ..." throws a warning when it's run from a script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

In my script I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

kill -9 $(ps aux | grep '[m]y_app' | awk '{print $2}')
sleep 3
ENV_VAR=val123 nohup my_app &
```

Why does it print this:

```
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

?

What's wrong with the "kill"?

When I run the line `kill -9 $(ps aux | grep '[m]y_app' | awk '{print $2}')` manually, it doesn't throw any warning.

Comment: The grep is probably returning more than one line. Put the output of the ps/grep in a temp var & print it out; also, you may want to add a "grep -v grep" and then a “head -1" to limit the output to one line. See also pgrep (but that would limit the portability).

Comment: Also: `grep '[m]y_app' ` probably isn't what you mean; do you want `egrep "[Mm]y_app"`? Alternatively, `grep -i ....` if that's the case.

Comment: @michael `grep '[m]y_app' probably isn't what you mean; ` -- why not?

Comment: @Oddamati The string `[m]` means to make sure that the first character is part of the character set consisting of the single letter `m`. If that is what you meant, then you could leave off the square brackets. If you want to have the first character case-insensitive, use either `grep -i` or `[Mm]`.

Comment: @DougO'Neal you're wrong

Comment: @Oddamati Pretty blunt. Am I wrong in what guessing what you're trying to accomplish or wrong in my solution? As a member for only two days, you might want to be a little more open to people who have been around for a while. I tried to answer your question `why not?` and I get a fairly rude answer.

Comment: @Oddamati Doug is in fact absolutely correct -- it's basics of grep regex. If you have questions (or disagreements) about them, your response will have to be more specific (and, preferably, cordial). These are equivalent: `grep "[t][h][e]" ...` and `grep "the" ...`  You might be thinking either case insensitivity, or perhaps optional?...but these are just guesses. The intent is not clear, but the brackets are clearly superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the exact same code (with some random apps) and it works just fine from both the command-line and the script (on Debian Jessie).

To debug your situation, try echoing what you are passing to the kill command inside the script...

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $(ps aux | grep '[m]y_app' | awk '{print $2}')
```

... to see if it returns the pid as expected.

Comment: I would suggest `set -x` instead, as a built-in means of seeing the invoked commands

Answer (score 2):

Try killing by processname:

```
pkill -9 my_app
```

Comment: 1) re-read my question --> your answer isn't not what I asked for 2) what if there're 2 or more instances of "my_app"? they all will be killed

Comment: @Oddamati It looks like this answer gives an alternative solution to the problem of killing the process `my_app`. Also, doesn't your pipeline also kill all instances of `my_app` just like the `pkill` solution?

Comment: `pkill` does send the specified signal to each matching process, as per `man pkill` ... Another equivalent option to this is simply `killall -9 my_app`, presuming all instances of `my_app` _want_ to be killed. The original question doesn't specific this as a requirement, but the original command in the question (if run successfully) would in fact also kill *all* `my_app` processes